# Update automatico después de cierto tiempo PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, web

estoy intentando actualizar un campo de una base de datos automaticamente después de que haya pasado cierto tiempo, intento hacerlo con PHP y JavaScript. Todo el código tiene que estar en la misma página que seria inicio.php Y necesito que se actualice solo cuando el usuario este en la página asi que pienso que con un cron job no me funcionaria. GRACIAS!!
Este es mi código:

```
<?php
require_once("conexion.php");
session_start();

  $tiempo_definido = 2;
  $fin = date('h:i:s');
  $_SESSION["fin"] = $fin;

      $inicio = strtotime($_SESSION["inicio"]);
    $fin = strtotime($_SESSION["fin"]);
    $imprimir = round(abs($fin - $inicio) / 60);
    echo $imprimir;

  if(isset($_POST["action"])) { 
    switch(sprintf("%d", $_POST["action"])) { 
        case 1:
            update(); // Llamar a tu función
            echo "Tarea completada!";
            break;
        default:
            echo "Error: Falta una acción";
    }
}
   function update(){
      $consulta_bd = $conexion->prepare("update usuarios set estado = 0 where usuario = '".$_SESSION['usu_id']."'");
    $consulta_bd->execute();

    session_destroy();
    header("Location:index.php");
    }



 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$(function() { 
    cron(); 
    function cron() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "inicio.php",
            data: {
                action: 1
            }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
    }
    setInterval(function() {
        cron();
    }, 10000); 
});
```

Comment: Holas Gustavo, quieres actualizar los datos cada cierto tiempo, pero ¿continuamente o sólo mientras el usuario está en la página? Dependiendo de lo que sea, se podría hacer de diferentes modos. Deberías [edit] la pregunta para añadir algo más de detalle y concretar el problema. Lee [ask] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y ganar tu primera medalla).

Comment: Quiero que se actualice solo cuando este el usuario en la página y gracias por tu consejo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el caso en concreto que planteas necesitas un cronjob que invoque la funcionalidad cada cierto tiempo. Dependiendo de sobre qué plataforma lo soportes así será la forma de programar el cronjob; pues la forma de hacerlo en Windows es diferente a Linux, por mencionar dos de las más utilizadas.

Comment: Seria bueno que coloques un ejemplo de `cronjob` en el Sistema Operativo que conoscas

Comment: Es que necesito que se actualice solo cuando el usuario este en la pagina.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera.

Con las funciones `setInterval` o `setTimeout` de javascript,
la primera realiza una acción y la repite cada cantidad de milisegundos indicada, y la segunda ejecuta una acción después de cierto tiempo, solo la ejecuta una sola vez(cada que la página es recargada claro está).

Ejemplo

```
setTimeout(function(){
// aqui puedes ejecutar un llamado ajax, que sería la inserción de datos a tu db
// la cual se ejecutaría después de 3 segundos, después de haber cargado la página
$.ajax({
    url:'http://mipagina/accion/guarda/datos',
    success:function(res){
        alert('acción de ejecución lanzada al servidor');
    },
    error:function(err){
        alert('Error sobre la conexión al servidor');
    }
});
}, 3000);
```